# combining parts of rows of different matrices matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation

I'm trying to combine parts of rows across two different matrices in matlab.  Each matrix is a 4x3x1 matrix.  I'm doing this in a loop, here is what I have so far...

```
    for x=1:1:popSize
        if success(x)<max(success);
            n = randi([2,4],1,1);
            population(:,:,x) = population((1:n),:,x)+population((n:4),:,randsample(indiv,1));
        end  


    end
```

Is this possible to do?  Should I turn each matrix into a column or row, save each part as a new variable, concatenate, and then reshape?

Comment: It's not very clear from your code.  How do you want to "combine" these rows?

Comment: I want to take a part of one row within a matrix and combine it with the "rest of the row" from a different matrix, preferably with the break point at random and the matrix that the rest of the row comes from random.  Population is a 4x3x10 matrix with each "indiv" as the 4x3 part.  A single indiv might look like 3,3,3;4,2,1;3,4,1;2,4,3